# How can I remove my upvote from a now out of date answer

Tags: discussion

In 2009 I asked a question that got a handful of useful answers which I upvoted.
One of those answers was not much more than a link to an external site, which was still useful.

Since then however, that external site is now gone, and so in the spirit of keeping SO data current, I went to remove my upvote. (It's no longer helpful).
I was unable to do so, getting a dialog that states:

> You last voted on this answer Aug 21 '09 at 20:11. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited.

Presumably I could work around this by editing the answer, but this doesn't feel right to me.
What do you think?

Comment: Flag to delete the useless non-answer. A link is not an answer. Especially when it's broken.

Answer (score 3):

If it's bad information, it needs to be fixed, downvoted, or removed.

Edit the answer.  Or link to it and we'll edit it.  Then remove your upvote if necessary.

Depending on the answer, it may also be appropriate to flag it for removal by a moderator.

Comment: The question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552756/can-silverlight-initiate-page-refreshes. The answer in question is the one by "Will"

Comment: [Direct link to the answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1313224/331508) That answer needed editing anyway!  (unformatted link, signature, spammy extraneous text).  Since the user is purged and a quick Google search did not recover the link, I'd flag it also.

Answer (score 0):

People usually downvote the answers with just a link for that specific reason : link rot.

Since your vote is locked, you can mark the answer for moderator's attention.